# Java ResultSet getDouble() unwanted rounding

Tags: java, sql

I have some doubles in a db table.
The format is like 45.4438838
When I get it from a Resultset:

```
rs.getDouble("value");
```

The returned number is 45.0

I checked and if I do 
     rs.getObject("value") ;
The result is in the correct form...

How to avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your jdbc driver.

Comment: Well you just said it - use `getObject` and parse it into double yourself.

Comment: What's the database? What's the JDBC driver version? I agree that this sounds like a JDBC driver issue? Try upgrading the JDBC driver.

Comment: I'm using sqlite, sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar as driver and I setted DOUBLE as datatype in sql

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry I got it,
I had doubles with comma decimal separator. (cause I'm Italian)
I replaced them with dot in database and now is working.